# Error 404 while targeting url in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, routes, react-router

For example if I open this link `https://cubeacloud.com/` , it will open easily
but if I target this specific link `https://cubeacloud.com/contact`
it will show me error 404  (open 2nd link in private tab)
I tried all the the things in routing

Routing code is given below

```js
import react from 'react';

import { Switch, Route, Router, BrowserRouterProps } from 'react-router-dom';

import LandingPage from './landingpage';
import AboutMe from './aboutme';
import Contact from './contact';
//projects
import Projects from './projects/projects';
import Graphics from './projects/graphics';
import Content from './projects/contant';
import Nav from '../navbar';
// import Resume from './resume';

//blogs
import Blogs from './blogs/blog';
import CryptoBlogs from './blogs/crypto';
import GamesBlogs from './blogs/games';
import ItBlogs from './blogs/it'
import EducationBlogs from './blogs//education'

//education
import Education from './education/education';
import Books from './education/books';
import Videos from './education/videos';
import Quiz from './education/quiz'
import Courses from './education/courses'
 
const Main = () => (
  
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/'} component={LandingPage} />
    <Route path="/aboutme" component={AboutMe} />
    <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
      {/* All Projects */}
    <Route path="/projects/projects" component={Projects} />
    <Route path="/projects/graphics" component={Graphics} />
    <Route path="/projects/content" component={Content} />
  {/* <Route path="/blog" component={Blogs} /> */}
   {/* All Education */}
   <Route path="/education/education" component={Education} />
  <Route path="/education/books" component={Books} />
  <Route path="/education/videos" component={Videos} />
  <Route path="/education/courses" component={Courses} />
  <Route path="/education/quiz" component={Quiz} />

      {/* All Blogs */}
      <Route path="/blogs/blog" component={Blogs} />
      <Route path="/blogs/crypto" component={CryptoBlogs} />
      <Route path="/blogs/education" component={EducationBlogs} />
      <Route path="/blogs/it" component={ItBlogs} />
      <Route path="/blogs/games" component={GamesBlogs} />
  </Switch>
)

export default Main;
```

Comment: Please don't SHOUT at people you're asking for help from

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Answer (score 0):

You have done right, also you have structured you `Main` React functional component very well, here only one thing you have to use `BrowserRouter`.

Please, wrap your `<Switch>...</Switch>` with `<BrowserRouter></BrowserRouter/>`

---

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


const Main = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      //your custom routes
    <Route> // not found route(404)
      <p>Not Found</p>
    </Route>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Main;
```

Comment: IT DOESN'T WORK :(

Comment: @HAHAHAHA, Please, put your browser console output screenshot.

Comment: @HAHAHAHA, do one thing, add `NotFound` `Route` to your router, and see this if it is working if not, means there is a problem with your Router is working fine.
But if also Not Found `Route` is not working means problem is with hosting. As I have updated my answer with Not found `Route`.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt3Yo.jpg)

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

WEB IS WORKING FINE ON LOCALHOST & LOCAL NETWORK,